# Extracting JOIN CONDITIONS definition from SQL statements in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm tring to figure out the pattern that can extract the join condition clause between to table in a SQL query, assuming the ANSI notation is in use.

For example, given the query:

```
Select a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*
  from a
 inner join b
   on a.c1 = b.c1
 left outer join c on
      c.c3 = b.c3 and b.c4 = c.c4
     and c.c5 = b.c5
 right join d on
  d.c9 = c.c9 
where d.c10 > 67 ;
```

I'd like to get:

```
1)  b
   on a.c1 = b.c1
2) c on
      c.c3 = b.c3 and b.c4 = c.c4
     and c.c5 = b.c5
3)  d on
  d.c9 = c.c9
```

I know the task is not that easy, but I'm not ment to get it to work perfectly, so a bit of noise in the match is considered feasible. Notice also the noise will be treatable in subsequent tasks.

I'm seraching the USER_VIEW in Oracle, so in order to use REGEXP_* functions, I made a source table to read from:

```
create table appo_view_text (viewname varchar2(30), viewtext clob);
insert into appo_view_text
 SELECT VIEW_NAME,to_lob(TEXT) FROM USER_VIEWS;
commit;
```

and here's the query to extract what I'm looking for:

```
with cfg as (
  select '(INNER\s+JOIN|LEFT(\s+OUTER)?\s+JOIN|RIGHT(\s+OUTER)?\s+JOIN).+?(\1|WHERE|GROUP BY|$)' pattern
       , 'i' modifiers
    from dual
)
SELECT VIEWNAME, REGEXP_SUBSTR(sourcetxt, cfg.pattern, 1, level, cfg.modifiers) aa, viewtext
  FROM ( select viewname,
                viewtext, 
                replace(replace(viewtext,chr(13)||chr(10),' '), chr(10), ' ') sourcetxt
                from appo_view_text 
                where viewname = 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME') --> Put here a view name
  cross join cfg
 connect by level <= regexp_count(sourcetxt, cfg.pattern, 1, cfg.modifiers)
 ;
```

You'll be noticing the regex pattern has an issue as it is defined in the query above: the (\1|$) element will cause the loss of half of the matches in the text.
I tried using (?:(\1|$)) instead, but that leads to just one row containing an empty string.

Any idea?

Comment: If you merge your `viewtext` in a single line, then you can create multiple matching groups like `select something from (table1) inner/left join (table2 on t1.col=t2.col and t2.col2=t1.col3) inner/left join .......  where .....`. So all the groups in `(braces)` are the one you want to return. Does this sound like something you want?

Comment: I didn't merged the view text in the table, but i alredy did in the extraction query (see "sourcetext" column). This didn't help, thoug

Comment: The main problem here is to find the beginning of a new table

Comment: Is it? And if we stop the search at the next INNER/LEFT/RIGH JOIN? As I wrote, a bit of noise in the match is feasible.

Comment: If you stop the search at some specific words, that should be pretty easy to  do, yes ^^ I'll add an answer, even if you found one. It might give you some ideas

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer myself:

```
with cfg as (
  select '(\WON\W).+?(WHERE|GROUP BY|(INNER\s+JOIN|LEFT(\s+OUTER)?\s+JOIN|RIGHT(\s+OUTER)?\s+JOIN|CROSS\s+JOIN)|$)' pattern
       , 'i' modifiers
    from dual
)
SELECT VIEWNAME, REGEXP_SUBSTR(sourcetxt, cfg.pattern, 1, level, cfg.modifiers) aa, viewtext, sourcetxt
  FROM ( select viewname,
                viewtext, 
                replace(replace(viewtext,chr(13)||chr(10),' '), chr(10), ' ') sourcetxt
                from appo_view_text 
                where viewname = 'VILASTAZIONE') --> Put here a view name
  cross join cfg
 connect by level <= regexp_count(sourcetxt, cfg.pattern, 1, cfg.modifiers)
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :
`(?i)(?<=join\s).*?(?=left|right|inner|where)`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Jybrws/1)
I am not sure if adding "where" to the list of delimiters is a good thing. You tell me !
**Edit :**
As it is not possible to use lookarounds, I suggest doing it with capturing groups :
`(?i)join\s(.*?)(?:left|right|inner|where)`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Jybrws/2)
Then you just have to throw away the match, what interests you here is in the capturing group 1.

Comment: It would work, but Oracle does not support "look around" operators (?=)

Comment: @Max: Oh ok, I didn't know that, sorry... I'll update my answer.